# Do game cards and digital copies have separate saves?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

My Animal Crossing: New Leaf 3DS came with AC:NL pre-installed, and I was wondering, if I were to purchase a new Animal Crossing New Leaf **cartridge**, would I be able to insert it into my 3DS (which already has the game pre-installed)? Would it count as a whole new game or would it continue the saved data from my pre-installed game? Or would it completely mess everything up? I'm sorry if this sounds confusing, but I just want to know if I could use a cartridge and have a whole separate game as if I had two 3DS's.

Comment: Based on the answer to [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122867/is-it-possible-to-play-new-leaf-on-multiple-systems-with-a-cartridge?rq=1) question, The game is saved to the cartridge, So I imagine by inserting a cartridge of the same game will treat it as two separate instances of the same game (meaning it won't pick up your save data). I can't be sure though, I haven't played the game.

Comment: In any case I don't think it will mess your save data up, if that's what you're worried about

Comment: Thank you! I'm just scared to buy a cartridge incase it doesn't work and I wasted my money! But we'll see!

Comment: I kept researching, and you should take a look at **[this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120534/can-i-make-separate-save-files-towns-mayors-in-animal-crossing-new-leaf?rq=1)** question - apparently, moving between systems can stuff up the save process. Be careful if you go down this path

Answer (score 5):

As the 3DS does not save cartidge save data to the system or SD card, there will be **no clash** between the two instances. They will be treated as **separate games**, with one file being on your download instance, and one on your cartridge.

StreetPass and SpotPass hits should go to both copies. Nintendo has fairly recently made available a tool to move save data from cartridge to download versions (albeit not the other way), so if you'd ever feel the need to do that it's completely possible.